# Kentico page update not update Physical table

Tags: kentico

I Have Kentico web site which has scheduler task that synchronise data with external Database.   Basically  few pages created from external database table. We have two methods for both create and update record in Kentico table.

For create we use

```
TreeNode page = TreeNode.New(Helper.ClassName_Campus);
page.SetValue("Title", "Title");
page.Insert(parentPage);
```

Create record works fine and update physical table data.

For update we use

```
 TreeNode page = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments(Helper.ClassName_Campus).OnSite("site").Where(" ID", QueryOperator.Equals, 1).FirstObject;
 page.SetValue("Title", "Title");
 page.Update();
```

Update method does works OK. when i go to page and form data i can see new data on the form field, but it doesn't  update actual physical table data. How can we update the actual physical data table when updating page. where is Kentico store form data after update.

This is the link we found on kentico web site for update table data.
https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Working+with+pages+in+the+API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kentico content tables (the ones bound to a page type) always contain **only published** data. In case you are using workflow/versioning the "new" data will be stored in **CMS_VersionHistory** table instead.

The solution is simply to publish the page by using something like:

```
    var page = DocumentHelper.GetDocument(1, new TreeProvider());
    page.DocumentName = "Update name";
    page.Publish();
```

Comment: Thanks for the  page.Publish() does  the trick. May i know why Insert work without publishing. Thanks.

Comment: It works because there are no "previous" versions of the page so it wouldn't be necessary to store those data in the version history :-)

Answer (score 1):

Did you use workflow for this pages?

You can try to using DocumentHelper.UpdateDocument(...) and specify there a TreeProvider, because maybe you don't have permission to update this page.

[Here's the link to API how manage the page](https://docs.kentico.com/display/API9/Pages#Pages-Pagemanagement)